# ASP.NET: button event does not fire, as its being blocked by another event on dropdown occurs (uxFromDate_TextChanged)

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, controls

I have a button which has a click event but its not firing on the first click. I suspect its something to do with that i am in dropdown box control so when i click the Button the event for the dropdown box occurs (textChanged) but it forgets about the click event :-)

Of course if i click it a second time it works.

Or if i click somewhere else first so that the event TextChange occurs and then click the Button the first time it executes..

Is this normal and what are more workarounds if any?

basically the TextChange event must fire but the button click event must fire as well.

All the events i am talking about are ASP.NET events.

here is some examples of the events i am using - both the button and dropdown

uxGetData is a button and uxToDate is a dropdown box

```
protected void uxGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    BindGrid();
    RefreshBindings();

}

protected void uxToDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date;
    bool valid = DateTime.TryParse(uxToDate.Text, out date);

    if (valid)
    {
        MyDate myDate= _repository.GetBetweenDate(date);
        if (myDate!= null)
            uxToMyDate.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(myDate.item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around is cancel the AutoPostBack of the drop down and use AJAX instead to update the oother drop down.

Second way around is to disable the button when the drop down selection is changed, using client side script, thus the user won't be able to click it - will prevent the confusion.

Can't think of third way around ATM so hope one of the above will be suitable. :)

Comment: Thanks Shadow, problem is that both in the event for Dropdown and button i need to do things server side i.e. database access

Comment: @Martin using the first way around you'll achieve that.. have the code currently in the uxToDate_TextChanged execute as response to AJAX request and it should work just fine, letting you click the button as well.

Comment: HI Shadow, I have set both items in Jquery clietn side .. 1 is change event of a textbox and the other si click of a button .. i.e $('#myTextbox').bind('change', function() {    AND also $('#myButton').bind('click', function() {   - Now if i just click the button i get the event (i have an alert in there), but i put something in the textbox and then clikc the button then the Change event fires (i have an alert) but the click event doesn't fire (no alert).

Comment: @Martin - OK found way around it. Use timer to execute the text changed code: `$('#myTextbox').bind('change', function() { window.setTimeout(function() { ..your stuff here.. }, 200); });` then button click will execute first, then text change.